# For numpy 2d array, how to find all pairs of adjacent elements?

Tags: python, numpy

Please help me. I want to ask about numpy matrix(2D array).

I have a 2d array `x` of which all element has `1` or `0` as the value. The shape of `x` is `(1000, 1000)` at most.

Let me define that:
 two distinct elements of `x` are said an adjacent pair if their indices (rows and columns respectively) differ `1` at most; and both have `1` as their values.

I want to know how to find all adjacent pairs on `A`.

Do I need to use a for loop?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the requirements can be met without explicit loops in numpy.

```
import numpy as np 

np.random.seed(1234)  # Make random array reproduceable

arr = np.random.randint( 0, 2, size = (10,10))

leftshifted = arr[ :, 1:] # Shift arr 1 col left, shape = (10,  9)
downshifted = arr[ 1: ]   # Shift arr 1 row down, shape = ( 9, 10)

hrows, hcols = np.where( arr[ :, :-1 ] & leftshifted ) 
# arr[ :,:-1 ] => ignore last column for the comparison
# returns rows and columns where arr and leftshifted = 1
# i.e. where two adjacent columns in a row are 1

vrows, vcols = np.where( arr[ :-1 ] & downshifted )
# arr[ :-1 ] => ignore last row for the comparison
# returns rows and columns where arr and downshifted = 1
# i.e. where two adjacent rows in a column are 1

print(arr, '\n')
# [[1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]
#  [1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
#  [1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]
#  [0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
#  [1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1]]

print('Row indices  :', hrows)
print('Col start ix :', hcols)
print('Col end ix   :', hcols+1)

# Row indices  : [0 0 0 1 2 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 9 9]
# Col start ix : [0 7 8 0 6 0 3 0 1 2 7 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 8]
# Col end ix   : [1 8 9 1 7 1 4 1 2 3 8 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 9]

print('\nStart Row:', vrows, '\nEnd Row  :',vrows+1, '\nColumn   :', vcols)

# Start Row: [0 0 1 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 8] 
# End Row  : [1 1 2 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 9] 
# Column   : [0 1 4 0 3 0 1 3 8 1 5 1 4 5 6 0 2 2]
```

Can an element be in more than one pair?  In the above it can be.
Do two diagonally touching elements count as a pair? If so a shifted_left_and_down array would be required too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It helps me a lot and solves my question. And "Yes" for both, "Can an element be in more than one pair? In the above it can be. Do two diagonally touching elements count as a pair?"